# Cannot passing value from non-gui mode if it match the IF Controller condition in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, groovy

I've below setup, i've tried to pass the value from non-gui mode but it doesn't work.

1. Config Element/User Defined Variable:
   portNum:8080
2. Config Element/HTTP Request Defaults:
   Port Number: ${__P(portNum,${portNum})}
3. I've created 2 If Controller something like below. It will execute those if controller if it match the port number
   First If Controller: ${__jexl3("${portNum}" == "8080")}
   Second If Controller: ${__jexl3("${portNum}" == "8888")}
4. It works when i run it from GUI mode but not from command line
   c:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin> jmeter -DportNum=8888 c:\Jmeter\TestVariable.jmx

From the command line, i've set the portNum value with 8888. but it didn't work. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`-D` command-line argument sets a [Java System Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), you won't be able to get its value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P), if you want to proceed - consider switching to i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which should look like:

```
${__groovy(System.getProperty('portNum'),)}
```

otherwise consider moving from `-D` to `-J` which sets a **JMeter Property** which can be accessed your way.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Also [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) so maybe it worth considering upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value of the `portNum` variable from the command line while running your JMeter script in non-GUI mode by using the following command:

```
jmeter -JportNum=8888 -n -t c:\Jmeter\TestVariable.jmx -l c:\Jmeter\results.jtl
```

Here, the `-J` option is used to set the value of a system property. The `-n` option runs JMeter in non-GUI mode and the `-t` option specifies the path to your JMeter script. The -l option specifies the path to the output results file.

Also, in the first If Controller, you need to change the condition to:

```
${__jexl3("${portNum}" == "8080")}
```

and in the second If Controller, you need to change the condition to:

```
${__jexl3("${portNum}" == "8888")}
```